# LinkedIn API のトークンが取得できない

Tags: api, oauth, rest

LinkedIn API を実行すべくトークンを取得しようとしているのですが、 Postman上で Request Token を実行した後に通常のログイン画面の表示 -> ログインとなってしまいアプリケーションの許可に進めません。

結果、トークンを取得できないため APIを実行することができないのですが、どこか間違っている箇所をご指摘願えますでしょうか。

Callback URL https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback
Auth URL https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps/verification/2f0c44bf-6c0b-44a3-bbdb-ade065064e65
Access Token URL https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken

Client ID とSecretは Appより取得しております。

Comment: 1年半前の記事ですが参考になるかも。[【LinkedIn】OAuth2 API まとめ](https://qiita.com/ight/items/124e3d83617b1e86ba1c), [Linkedin プロフィール情報の取得](https://qiita.com/donaldchi/items/afe2db42c8a6a71c76de) そしてLinkedInのページでしょう。[Permissions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/permissions), [Authorization Code Flow (3-legged OAuth)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow), [Client Credential Flow (2-legged OAuth)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow)

Answer (score 0):

> Auth URL https://www.linkedin.com/developers/apps/verification/2f0c44bf-6c0b-44a3-bbdb-ade065064e65

少なくともこれは違いますね。「Auth URL」にはLinkedInのOAuth 2.0認可エンドポイント（以下）を指定すべきなので。

https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization

参考：
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/context

Comment: ありがとうございます。 Auth URL を変更しましたが変化はない様です。。

Comment: どのようなリクエストに対してどのようなレスポンスが返ってきているか、質問に追記して下さい。